# pyspark read json column from dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataframe with json content and i would like to read the json and create a dataframe with multiple columns

| data |
| --- |
| [{"name": "john","lastname": "kenny","zip": "12345"},{"name": "larry","lastname": "free","zip": "98765"}] |

i would like to read the above json from a dataframe column and create a dataframe as below

| name | lastname | zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | kenny | 12345 |
| larry | free | 98765 |

here is my code but i'm seeing nulls while extracting

```
schema = StructType(
     [
      StructField('name', StringType(), True),
      StructField('lastname', StringType(), True),
      StructField('zip', StringType(), True)
     ]
)
df = df.withColumn("data", F.from_json("data", schema))
df = df.select("data").select(F.col("data.*"))
df.show()
```

| name | lastname | zip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema of the json string in `data` should be an array of struct, modified as follows:

```
schema = ArrayType(
    StructType(
        [
            StructField('name', StringType(), True),
            StructField('lastname', StringType(), True),
            StructField('zip', StringType(), True)
        ]
    )
)
df = df.withColumn('data', F.from_json('data', schema)).selectExpr('inline(data)')
df.show(truncate=False)
```